# php getimagesize function is freezing server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, getimagesize

I'm having a problem with the getimagesize function, it freezes the server.

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
        <span>{{$category->thumb}}</span>
         <div class="box-categoria">
            <a href="{{$category->generateCategoryUrl()}}">
                @if(isset($category->thumb)&&$category->thumb != ""&&getimagesize($category->thumb))
                    <img src="{{$category->thumb}}" width="150"/>
                @else
                    <img src="{{asset('assets/images/no-thumb.jpg')}}" width="150"/>
                @endif
                <div class="overlay"></div>

            </a>
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

This works normally in another computers, it works even in the production server.

This project uses the Laravel framework, artisan server and the url of the image is like this:

http://www.portaldamarcaelectrolux.com.br/owners/575889d6024f03012e4273b6/categories/f18058073cffbcba22945e57544b120a.jpg

Thanks

Comment: What do you consider "freezes the server"? Do you have any error log?

Comment: Just a timeout
local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded' in D:\Projetos\TradeSquashV2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php:56

Comment: The page keeping loading in the browser

Comment: The image loads with no problems too, if I call the url directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very strange to put this check (`getimagesize`) in a blade view. It's back-end logic, and very bad for the performance to check this on the fly. A better way is to put this logic simplified like below in your blade view *without the if-else condition*.

```
<img src="{{$category->thumb}}" width="150" onerror="this.src='/assets/images/no-thumb.jpg';"/>
```

So if the thumb doesn't exist, the image `no-thumb` will be loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, this project is an old one, and the company has "changed the team", I'm new here, now it's just me to keep this project and improve it.

Comment: Well, I don't know why the function freezes, but this solved my problem. thanks a lot